# Only display numbers in PHP

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
$string = "Sehr mild mit Höchstwerten von 11 bis 14 Grad, in Hochlagen 6 bis 10 Grad.";
```

How can I display only the numbers like 14, 11, 6 etc. and how can I get the numbers singly in a variable?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read this article and update your answer: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Sehr mild mit Höchstwerten von 11 bis 14 Grad, in Hochlagen 6 bis 10 Grad.';

$newString = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$string);

echo $newString;
```

Above regex will trim everything that isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'Sehr mild mit Höchstwerten von 11 bis 14 Grad, in Hochlagen 6 bis 10 Grad.';

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);

$var = implode(' ', $matches[0]); 

echo $var;
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I get one single value? Like $match[0] or something?

Comment: which value? @Freddy

Comment: it does not matter.  I want to be able to call each number individually.

Comment: I already added this each numbered print individually check this one: https://paiza.io/projects/zRiynrTLQzzZ7ajr1fg_Dw

Comment: please pay attention when editing question like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59749211/8620333 .. don't automatically convert any code to a snippet. The OP is using SASS and no CSS so it cannot got into snippet. Read the code and check it before doing such action please

Comment: Which variable do I use to get the individual numbers?

Comment: Please clarify your question specifically I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP `intval()` function and `preg_replace` with some regex expressions `('/[^0-9]+/')`.

```
$text = "Sehr mild mit Höchstwerten von 11 bis 14 Grad, in Hochlagen 6 bis 10 Grad.";

$var = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $text), 10);

echo $var;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get a syntax error here: 
 syntax error, unexpected '`', expecting ')'

Comment: I fixed it, that was caused by a ( ' ) sign after the second $text.